# Reference function or create a new function that only calls another?

Tags: python, function, coding-style

```
def a(something):
    return something*something

#Case I - referencing
b = a
#Case II - creating a new function to call the first
def b(something):
    return a(something)
```

Which is better style? Are there drawbacks to either?

Comment: Why do you want to do either of these, rather than just referring to a by its name?

Comment: I'm making a sort of plugin type thing, where each module needs to implement a certain module, but can possibly use a premade one that will work on most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b = a` means calls to `b` will be faster (no overhead), but introspection (e.g. `help(b)`) will show the name `a`, and `a`'s docstring.  Unless the latter issues are a killer for your specific application (some kind of tutorial, for example), the speed advantage normally wins the case.

Consider, e.g. in ref.py:

```
def a(something):
    return something*something

#Case I - referencing
b1 = a
#Case II - creating a new function to call the first
def b2(something):
    return a(something)
```

Now:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import ref' 'ref.a(23)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.716 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import ref' 'ref.b1(23)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.702 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import ref' 'ref.b2(23)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.958 usec per loop
```

I.e., calls to `b1` (pure referencing) are just as fast as calls to `a` (actually appear 2% faster in this run, but that's well within "the noise" of measurement;-), calls to `b2` (entirely new function which internally calls `a`) incur a 20% overhead -- not a killer, but normally something to avoid unless that performance sacrifice buys you something specific that's quite important for your use case.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what you need.

```
def a(something):
    return something*something

b = a

def a(something):
    return something+something

>>> b(3)
9
>>> a(3)
7
```

Whereas if you did:

```
b = lambda x:a(x)
```

b and a will always returns the same

If you want to optimize an extra function call out the first way is better, if you want b and a to always return the same thing the second way is better.

Comment: ...and I don't think the extra function call is worth optimizing out in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

First doesn't generate a new function, should be better.

Answer (score 0):

Function call creates overhead. Case I is faster. Case II creates new function unrelated function.

Why would you need Case II?